# Stack Overflow 10月「DevDays」

Tags: 討議

**チケットは好評発売中です！クリックしてください：http://devdays.peatix.com**

Stack Overflowの社長[ジョエル・スポルスキ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A7%E3%82%A8%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BB%E3%82%B9%E3%83%9D%E3%83%AB%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AD)が来日します。

> 10月に来日します！Stack Overflow社では開発者の力になれることは何でもやろうと考えています。その一つとして、開発者のみなさんが主役のイベントの開催を計画しています。参加しませんか？
>
> - [Twitterより](https://twitter.com/spolsky/status/641424286390075392)

当コミュニティのユーザーの参加を優先したいので、もし興味があれば、下記のアンケートをご記入よろしくお願いします。

<s>https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1ODw8hZvVeKbPysBG8d4LX2djYUriikv5hS925kBiZCE/viewform</s>

<sup>※ 当サイトで登録されたメールを利用してください。上記のTwitter経由のリンクですでに回答した場合、ここでも不要ですが、メールアドレスは当サイトに登録した際を使ってください。</sup>

10月9日（金）に開催する予定です。

Comment: これこそコミュニティ広告のネタに良さそうですね

Comment: どこでこのイベントをやりますか?

Comment: @KiYugadgeter 東京です

Comment: @jmac 東京のどこですか?

Comment: http://www.hotel-azur.com/access/ ここですよね？東京の浜松町駅や竹芝駅が近いです。

Comment: @KiYugadgeter 浜松町駅です。

Comment: @Sieg はい、そのとおりです。